# Printing value of register, assembly x8086

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

Hello I'm currenty writing a program and I need to print the value of the register `AX` to the screen. I was thinking of few ways, but they didn't work. Any ideas how to make it? for instance `ax` = 0abcdh.

Comment: Please mention what did you tried so and what is your errors.

Comment: Convert to a hex string, print it. What's the problem? Where is your attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to divide the register's value in different parts.

Example: Hexadecimal output:

```
  MOV CX, 4
next_digit:
  PUSH CX
  MOV CL, 4
  ROL AX, CL
  PUSH AX
  AND AL, 0Fh
  ADD AL, '0'
  CMP AL, '9'
  JLE not_a_letter
  ADD AL, 'A'-'9'-1
not_a_letter:
  ; Now write the character AL to the screen
  POP AX
  POP CX
  LOOP next_digit
```

This code will destroy the CX register's content so you'll have to save it on stack if you do not want to modify the CX register.

The line "Now write the character AL to the screen" is operating system dependent.

If you want decimal output it is a bit more tricky. You'll have to use the DIV instruction and divide by 10. You'll get the digits from the right to the left!!!